# How can i get failed http request details in jmeter via mail?

Tags: email, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to send the mail through jmeter for failed http request, I want to know the sampler details like name of http request?
I have added if controller to check the assertion of previously running request sand send a mail if it fails.It gives me error message 
"**Message from Jmeter thread # Test failed: code expected to match /200/**" 
But I want to know the name of http request which has been failed so i can know specifically which request is failing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) to get the previous sampler details using the following code:

```
def sampler = ctx.getPreviousSampler()
```

Example usage:

```
def previousSamplerName = ctx.getPreviousSampler().getName()
log.info("Failed sampler name: " + previousSamplerName)
vars.put("SamplerName", previousSamplerName)
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter PreProcessor get previous sampler name]

If everything goes fine you will be able to access previous sampler name as `${SamplerName}` in the SMTP Request sampler

- `ctx` is a shorthand to [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class instance, see the JavaDoc for available methods and fields
- `vars` is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, it provides read/write access to all JMeter Variables in scope.

Also check out [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) guide to get familiarized with using Groovy in JMeter tests.

Comment: Thanx it works for me!! Can I pass the whole response to the mail sampler? I need to know what error message does the http request gets?

Comment: `vars.put("wholeResponse", ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString())`